# Why java process keeps on sending and receiving packets thereby consuming internet continuously?

Tags: networking, internet, java

I was just having a look at my network activity as my internet bill for the month was way beyond my reach and i found that the java process in my mac has been continuously sending and receiving data in other words consuming all my bandwidth for nothing.

Can you tell me why this happens and how to stop it?

I have also attached a screenshot, just as a reference.
[image]

Comment: Did you run a java update? 97.4MB seems like quite a lot for just phoning home to check for updates.

Comment: Without the complete command line of this process, you can't know what it's running. IIRC, `ps aux` ought to do the job.

Comment: Latest version of Java for OS/X is 56.7 MB.

Comment: Does Viewing by All Processes, Hierarchically give any clues as to which process is using/being used by the java instance?